# Cumulative count of unique values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a huge dictionary dd{} where I have people and sets of fruits they prefer:

```
A set(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberries'])
B set(['Banana', 'Strawberries', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Dates'])
C set(['Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Grapes'])
A set(['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Lemon'])
```

I want a cumulative count for the fruits, meaning for the 1st person, the number of his preferred fruits, for the 2nd person, the number of fruits belonging to the previous person PLUS the number of his own preferred fruits that didn't exist in the previous person's set and so on.  I want to have a result like this:

```
1 3
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

The incrementing numbers in the first column are the persons and the second column the cumulative number of the fruits. How do I implement this in Python? 
Thanks, Adia.

Comment: Your output doesn't correspond to the problem definition: for person C `'Apple'` doesn't exist in the previous person's (B's) set.

Comment: Are you sure the fourth person is an `A`? How do you store this in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
allFruits = set()
for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted(dd.iteritems()), 1):
    allFruits.update(v)
    print i, len(allFruits)
```

This works for Python 2.6 and newer. For older versions try this:

```
allFruits = set()
for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted(dd.iteritems())):
    allFruits.update(v)
    print i+1, len(allFruits)
```

Input:

```
dd = {'A': set(['Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberries']),
      'B': set(['Banana', 'Dates', 'Kiwi', 'Orange', 'Strawberries']),
      'C': set(['Apple', 'Grapes', 'Kiwi']),
      'D': set(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon', 'Orange'])}
```

Output:

```
1 3
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Comment: Yeah. Don't forget to sort the keys.

Comment: Also, outputting keys instead of indices in the first column, the code could be made much prettier.

Comment: `enumerate` has start parameter.

Comment: Thanks eumiro. When I apply the code on the dictionary which is much bigger than the example given, it gives the error message 'enumerate() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)'. Why is that?

Comment: @Adia - it means you are using Python 2.5 or older. See my edit.